# How to get the image size in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple image gallery with different image size. I'm going to get the width of the current image and assign it to it's parent div using jquery but I can't seem to get it working. Thanks for any help.

```
var imgWidth = $("#image").width();
$("#gallery").css({ width : imgWidth });
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
 <img src="123.jpg" id="image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems ok. But you may be trying when the image hasn't been loaded yet. `$(document).ready` **wouldn't help in this case**.
Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var imgWidth = $("#image").width();
  $("#gallery").width(imgWidth);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Or you can do "load" right on the image, don't have to wait for everything to load that way. `$("#image").load(function(){})`

Comment: Still can't get it to work. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtD7q/) .I'm new to jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify "px"

Like so:

```
var imgWidth = $("#image").width();
$("#gallery").css({ width : imgWidth+"px" });
```

Assuming the image is loaded when your javascript is executing this should work. If not you'll have to place this code inside a `$(window).load(function(){});` as Edgar says or possibly even a `$("#image").load(function(){});`.

Comment: +1 Thanks rayan. But i still can't get it to work. please take a look at this sample code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtD7q/).

Comment: @NL500: Try this jsfiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/LtD7q/3/ as James said you didn't have the jQuery framework selected.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to kick yourself for this......

Your jsfiddle was set to use mootools not jQuery.

Here's a working update [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LtD7q/1/)